# Rendering problems when zooming and panning on canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I copied example code from this site https://tylerewillis.com/page/canvas-image-zoom

The code on the side seems to work pretty well, although things can be improved.

When I execute my code run into these problems:

On the mentioned website, when you enter the image/canvas on the right or left bottom and you use the mouse wheel to zoom, **that part** of the image is being zoomed. (Now you can start panning also).

But when I execute my code, same browser, same machine, that part of the image is not zoomed.

And when I enter the image/canvas on the top side, my image gets malformed. It looks like this:

[image]

It happens on my local machine and also with the CodePen (https://codepen.io/r-w-c/details/JjwEVmx) I have made.

The obvious explanation is that my code is not the same. It is easy to make a small error.
But the weird things is, I also made a copy of the webpage using 'Save As' in Chrome with exactly the same result!

Can anybody tell me what causes these problems? Code improvements are also welcome.

Below the same code as in the CodePen ... Thanks!

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas')
canvas.width = 500
canvas.height = 325
canvas.top = canvas.offsetTop + 220
canvas.left = canvas.offsetLeft
var c = canvas.getContext('2d')

function createImage(intensity, posX, posY) {
    var width = canvas.width + (intensity * (canvas.width / canvas.height))
    var height = canvas.height + intensity
    var x = 0 - (posX / canvas.width) * (width - canvas.width)
    var y = 0 - (posY / canvas.height) * (height - canvas.height)

    var img = new Image
    img.onload = () => {
        c.drawImage(img,x,y, width, height)
    }
    img.src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/373912/pexels-photo-373912.jpeg'
}
createImage(0, 0, 0)

var y = 0, x = 0
canvas.onmousemove = (e) => {
    x = e.pageX - canvas.left, y = e.pageY - canvas.top
    createImage(intensity,x,y)
}
var intensity = 0
canvas.onwheel = (e) => {
    if (e.deltaY < 0) {
        intensity = (intensity + e.deltaY > 0) ? intensity + e.deltaY : 0
    } else {
        intensity += e.deltaY
    }
    createImage(intensity, x, y)
}

canvas.onmouseover = () => {
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'hidden'
}
canvas.onmouseleave = () => {
    document.querySelector('body').style.overflow = 'visible'
}
```

```css
#canvas {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<canvas class="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Can you explain what you think the various parts of this code do? Because reading through this, there is no way it's going to do what you think it's supposed to do, and the problem you're asking about is just a symptom of the larger problem of this code not being pan/zoom code. (the image isn't malformed at all, you just keep drawing new images on top of the previously drawn image, because you don't clear the canvas before drawing a new image)

Comment: @Mike, you are right, but in the example code, the canvas isn't cleared either, but it seems to work, although flawed. I just wanted it to work on my side, but it doesn't. There is more than one problem with the code. But I am more looking for an explanation why it doesn't work in my environment. I will look into the 'not clearng the canvas part'. Thanks. Anymore suggestions?

Comment: Yes: find a different page that shows how to add pan/zoom to canvas. Loads of examples, pick one that uses modern JS and canvas transform/scale instructions instead so you don't spend any more time trying to fix whatever this is.

Comment: The code is easy to follow. It is the createImage function where the image is drawn. Every time a new image is created and loaded. Seems quite expensive to me. It is drawn on the canvas by calling c.drawImage(img,x,y). I see some problems here, but still wonder how it could work in the original code. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not that it's easy to follow, it's that it's super weird in so many ways that it's far better to just find a different tutorial than try to fix this one. E.g. https://codepen.io/pomax-the-scripter/pen/MWZpwjB based on https://github.com/roblouie/canvas-pan-and-zoom - works immediately, uses normal JS.

Comment: @Mike: I will take your advise. (Still worry what was going on with the weird code, but he you are right, I (we) have got better things to do....)

And thanks for the CodePen. Really appreciated!